# Silverstripe Tests Can't find page from fixture

Tags: testing, silverstripe

I'm not understanding how to do functional tests.

I want to get going by running simple functional tests:

```
class PageTest extends FunctionalTest{

  static $fixture_file = 'mysite/tests/PageTest.yml';

    public function testDirectorView() {
        $response1 = Director::test('/hello', null, null);               
        $this->assertTrue(
          strpos(
            $response1->getBody(), 
            '<h3>Hello World</h3>'
          ) !== false);        
    }  
}
```

Using the following fixture

```
Page:
    hello:
        Title: HelloWorld
```

However my test fails and the response body shows i am fetching a 404.

How can i correctly get the page response / set up the fixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following

```
class PageTest extends FunctionalTest{

static $fixture_file = 'mysite/tests/PageTest.yml';

static $use_draft_site = true;

public function testDirectorView() {
    $page = $this->objFromFixture('Page','hello');
    $response1 = $this->get($page->RelativeLink());               
    $this->assertTrue(
      strpos(
        $response1->getBody(), 
        '<h3>Hello World</h3>'
      ) !== false);        
}  
}
```

Comment: yep that did it.  its a shame i can't use all the nice  "assertExactMatchBySelector" type syntax as i'm using mamp - might finally move onto something more beardy like a proper homebrew installation of php.  Thanks very much